# SELECT only records with future date in field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to select future events only

```
event    s_date    start_time  end_time
event6   2015-01-30  19:45:00  21:45:00
event5   2015-01-29  20:45:00  21:45:00
event4   2015-01-29  19:45:00  21:45:00
event3   2015-01-28  00:30:00  03:00:00
event2   2015-01-27  09:00:00  11:00:00
event1   2015-01-26  19:45:00  21:45:00
```

I tried this but doesn't get the right results

```
SELECT s_date, DATE_FORMAT(s_date, '%W %D %M') AS date, CONCAT(s_date, ' ', end_time) AS dt
FROM schedule
GROUP BY s_date
HAVING dt >= NOW()
```

Comment: what do you mean by *future* records?

Comment: i mean future events

Comment: @SimoE. Do the times belong to the same day? In other words: do you have scenarios like 'start = '2015-01-29 23:59'` and `end = '2015-01-30 00:01'`?

Comment: yes all events have start and end time in the same day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `group by`, but you're not aggregating any column... so the value you get when evaluating that 'concat()` expression will be random.

Check [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd729/5) for the solution:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd729/5)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table schedule(
  event varchar(50),
  s_date date,
  start_time time,
  end_time time
);

insert into schedule 
values ('event6', '2015-01-30', '19:45:00', '21:45:00')
     , ('event5', '2015-01-29', '20:45:00', '21:45:00')
     , ('event4', '2015-01-29', '19:45:00', '21:45:00')
     , ('event3', '2015-01-28', '00:30:00', '03:00:00')
     , ('event2', '2015-01-27', '09:00:00', '11:00:00')
     , ('event1', '2015-01-26', '19:45:00', '21:45:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
select s.*
from schedule as s
where concat(s_date, ' ', end_time) > now()
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd729/5/1)**:

```sql
|  EVENT |                         S_DATE |                     START_TIME |                       END_TIME |
|--------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| event6 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 19:45:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:45:00+0000 |
| event5 | January, 29 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 20:45:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:45:00+0000 |
| event4 | January, 29 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 19:45:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:45:00+0000 |
| event3 | January, 28 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:30:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 03:00:00+0000 |
```

**Query 2**:

```sql
-- Little trick: 
-- In MySQL you can use HAVING without GROUP BY
-- to filter data using column aliases

select s.*, concat(s_date, ' ', end_time) as e_datetime
from schedule as s
having e_datetime > now()
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd729/5/2)**:

```sql
|  EVENT |                         S_DATE |                     START_TIME |                       END_TIME |          E_DATETIME |
|--------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|---------------------|
| event6 | January, 30 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 19:45:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:45:00+0000 | 2015-01-30 21:45:00 |
| event5 | January, 29 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 20:45:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:45:00+0000 | 2015-01-29 21:45:00 |
| event4 | January, 29 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 19:45:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:45:00+0000 | 2015-01-29 21:45:00 |
| event3 | January, 28 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:30:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 03:00:00+0000 | 2015-01-28 03:00:00 |
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TIMESTAMP()` to concatenate the date and time, then compare that to the current time.

For example, to get a list of events that haven't started yet:

```
SELECT 
  event, start_time, end_time
FROM
  events
WHERE
  TIMESTAMP(s_date, start_time) > NOW()
;
```

Note that this assumes that start_time and end_time are of type `TIME`. You should consider eliminating the `s_date` field entirely and storing both `start_time` and `end_time` as `DATETIME` fields.

Remember not to use `TIMESTAMP` fields for this. Although they look similar, `TIMESTAMP` will update whenever the record changes, whereas `DATETIME` just stores the value you explicitly give it.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with your `GROUP BY` clause. If you use this, it will only give you one event for each date. It won't even give you the first event for that date since you are not explicitly setting an order.

If you could clarify your intent on that portion, I'd be happy to try to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right :

```
select * from 
(select s_date, max(concat(s_date,' ',start_time)) as dt
from schedule 
group by s_date
) as x
where STR_TO_DATE(x.dt, '%Y-%c-%e %r') >= NOW()
```

I assume that *future events* is events that not aired yet.